# Could not access type LoggingAdapter in value akka.event

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, spray

I migrated from Scala 2.10.8 to 2.11.7 and Akka 2.1.2 to 2.3.14. I did lot of changes in *.sbt and source also. Now, I am getting some issue. I check online, but I did not get actual cause. I think the spray version is not suite to Akka version. But which version of Spray I have to use for Akka 2.3.14, I did not get any information yet online and Akka documents also.

The Issue is:

```
[error] missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'LoggingContext.class'.
[error] Could not access type LoggingAdapter in value akka.event,
[error] because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
[error] missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'LoggingContext.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of akka.event.
```

My Project dependency is this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tp1ruackt9tued6/dependencyTree2.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use spray, the latest version of Akka you may use is 2.2.x as you can see [in their documentation](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.4/spray-can/dependencies/).

In case that you have to use a newer version of Akka, you will have to use Akka HTTP and follow their [migration guide](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/migration-guide/migration-from-spray.html?_ga=2.50124838.1090941987.1497539405-1143660618.1497539405).